# Access to module config in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

How I can get access to my module config from the controller?

Comment: Are you talking about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680939/how-can-i-access-the-configuration-of-a-zend-framework-application-from-a-contro

Comment: I knew about this decision, but I think in the new ZF2 it can be done more elegant. Because I define method getConfig in the my Module class.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I am really surprised at how obscure this is, because I had exactly the same problem and could not find a definitive answer. One would think the ZF2 documentation would say something about this. Anyhow, using trial and error, I came across this *extremely* simple answer:

#### Inside controller functions:

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
```

#### Inside Module class functions (the `Module.php` file):

```
$config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Config');
```

whereas `$e` is an instance of `Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent`

---

In general, the config is accessible from anywhere you have access to the global service manager since the config array is registered as a service named `Config`. *(Note the uppercase `C`.)*

This returns an array of the union of application.config.php (global and local) and your module.config.php. You can then access the array elements as you need to.

Even though the OP is quite old now, I hope this saves someone the hour or more it took me to get to this answer.

Comment: From where($this) are you calling this line of code mate?

Comment: @kaziTanvirAhsan from one of the controller's methods, I'd imagine.

Comment: Yes; I was able to do this from a controller that extends AbstractRestfulController

Comment: Well it's not a simple answer if we don't know what is "$this". I've tried it from a module for instance and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

What exactly do you want to do in your controller with the module configuration? Is it something that can't be done by having the DI container inject a fully configured object into your controller instead?

For example, [Rob Allen's Getting Started with Zend Framework 2](http://akrabat.com/getting-started-with-zend-framework-2/) gives this example of injecting a configured Zend\Db\Table instance into a controller:

```
return array(
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            'album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
        'Album\Controller\AlbumController' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'albumTable' => 'Album\Model\AlbumTable',
            ),
        ),
        'Album\Model\AlbumTable' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'config' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Mysqli',
        )),
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Mysqli' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'config' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'rob',
                    'password' => '123456',
                    'dbname' => 'zf2tutorial',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        ...
```

If you need to do additional initialization after the application has been fully bootstrapped, you could attach an init method to the bootstrap event, in your Module class. A [blog post by Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://mwop.net/blog/267-Getting-started-writing-ZF2-modules) gives this example:

```
use Zend\EventManager\StaticEventManager,
Zend\Module\Manager as ModuleManager

class Module
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $manager)
    {
        $events = StaticEventManager::getInstance();
        $events->attach('bootstrap', 'bootstrap', array($this, 'doMoarInit'));
    }

    public function doMoarInit($e)
    {
        $application = $e->getParam('application');
        $modules     = $e->getParam('modules');

        $locator = $application->getLocator();
        $router  = $application->getRouter();
        $config  = $modules->getMergedConfig();

        // do something with the above!
    }
}
```

Would either of these approaches do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

for Beta5, you can add function like this in Module.php

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{ 
    $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
          $config = $e->getApplication()->getConfiguration();
          $controller = $e->getTarget();
          $controller->config = $config;
    });
 }
```

in controller, you can get config :

```
print_r($this->config);
```

Answer (score 3):

To read module-only config your module should just implement LocatorRegisteredInterface

Before:

```
namespace Application;

class Module
{
   // ...
}
```

After:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\LocatorRegisteredInterface;

class Module implements LocatorRegisteredInterface
{
   // ...
}
```

That implementation says LocatorRegistrationListener to save module intance in service locator as *namespace*\Module

Then anywhere you can get access to your module:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        /** @var \Application\Module $module */
        $module = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Module');
        $moduleOnlyConfig = $module->getConfig();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pull request ready now](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/786) which pulls the module class (so the modules/foo/Module.php `Foo\Module` class) from the DI container. This gives several advantages, but you are also able to grab that module instance another time if you have access to the `Zend\Di\Locator`.

If your action controller extends the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController`, then your controller is LocatorAware. Meaning, upon instantiation your controller is injected with the locator knowing about modules. So, you can pull the module class from the DIC in your controller. Now, when your module consumes a config file and stores this inside the module class instance, you can create a getter to access that config data from any class with a locator. You probably have already an accessor with your module `Foo\Module::getConfig()`

While ZF2 is heavily under development and perhaps this code will change later on, this feature is currently covered by [this test](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/zf2/blob/02f4b18545b099d394d0f164f8f7a799495f74c5/tests/Zend/Module/Listener/LocatorRegistrationListenerTest.php), with this the most relevant part:

```
$sharedInstance = $locator->instanceManager()->getSharedInstance('ListenerTestModule\Module');

$this->assertInstanceOf('ListenerTestModule\Module', $sharedInstance);
```

So with `$sharedInstance` your module class, you can access the config from there. I expect a shorthand for this feature soon, but this can only be done after PR #786 has been merged in ZF2 master.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface from your model. And then you can set setServiceLocator() and getServiceLocator() which give you direct access to the service manager. Take a look at this code sample https://gist.github.com/ppeiris/7308289

Comment: This is a good answer since it's considered to a bad practise to call ServiceLocator within any controller. You need to call it via a service(model)

Answer (score 0):

I created the module with controller plugin and view helper for reading a config in controllers and views. [GitHub link](https://github.com/tasmaniski/zf2-config-helper) __ [Composer link](https://packagist.org/packages/tasmaniski/zf2-config-helper)

*Install it via composer*

```
composer require tasmaniski/zf2-config-helper
```

*Register new module "**ConfigHelper**" in your **config/application.config.php** file*

```
'modules' => array(
    '...',
    'ConfigHelper'
),
```

*Use it in controller and view files*

```
echo $this->configHelp('key_from_config'); // read specific key from config 

$config = $this->configHelp(); // return config object Zend\Config\Config
echo $config->key_from_config;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also access any config value anywhere by this hack/tricks

```
$configReader = new ConfigReader();
$configData = $configReader->fromFile('./config.ini');
$config = new Config($configData, true);
```