# Zend framework 2 : How do I access modules config value from a controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

In module.config.php file, I have set value for 'password_has_type'. And in controller I want to access that. Here is my module.config.php file:

```
'auth' => array(
    'password_hash_type' => 'sha512',
),
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            'auth' => 'Auth\Controller\AuthController',
            'auth_login_form' => 'Auth\Form\LoginForm',
        ),...
```

In `controller`, I have used

```
use Auth\Module
```

and in `Action` method I try to get access value by

```
echo Module::getOption('password_hash_type');
```

But I could not get any value?

So please can anybody help me to get that value ?

Comment: How about `$auth = Module::getOption('auth'); echo $auth['password_hash_type'];` ?

Comment: or set the array in registry and get it anywhere

Answer (score 5):

Please see my answer at [Access to module config in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957274/access-to-module-config-in-zend-framework-2/13034265#13034265).

But to make it more concrete to your question, you would do this:

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
$pwht = $config['auth']['password_hash_type'];
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help of aliases and parameters. Put it into `di->instance` array:

```
'Auth\Controller\AuthController' => array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'passwordHashType' => 'sha512'
    )
),
```

And it is your controller:

```
namespace Auth\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

class AuthController extends ActionController
{
    protected $passwordHashType;

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo $this->passwordHashType;
    }

    public function setPasswordHashType($passwordHashType)
    {
        $this->passwordHashType = $passwordHashType;
        return $this;
    }
}
```